# Why the disparity between Filestream size and Container folder size?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-size, filestream

I have an issue with one of my SQL Server 2014 databases. It appears to me that the Filestream size is significantly larger than the actual Filestream container folder size? ~360Mb larger.

The following query give me the location and size of the Filestream objects:

```
SELECT physical_name, (Size * 8 / 1024) AS SizeMb
FROM sys.database_files WHERE type = 2

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\FilestreamDB_FS 
867418
```

Yet if I go to file explorer right click and properties to view the size of the folder it is 502Gb:

[image: filestream container folder size]

These figures used to match until 2 weeks ago. Why the disparity?

I am not convinced that it is compression. The reason is that until about 2 weeks ago Filestream was growing slowly and was only ~490Gb but over the weekend of the 30th June the size suddenly jumped (see attached image) and no longer matches the folder size - which it used to. The only things running at the weekend would be maintenance jobs, such as index rebuild etc.

I have read [How It Works: FileStream (RsFx) Garbage Collection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2011/06/23/how-it-works-filestream-rsfx-garbage-collection/) and have tried to force the garbage collector to run; however, it did not free up any extra space. This database is in simple recovery mode.

#### Additional information

Database Size:

[image: Database Size]

[image]

Database Size History:

[image]